# Connecting each column for each row in r ggplot2 scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three columns: "original", "pos1", "pos2". Each row is an individual. I want to create a scatterplot where "original" is on the x-axis, and pos1 and pos2 values are on the y-axis. So each original will have a pos1 dot and a pos2 dot. I can create two different colors to distinguish pos1 and pos2 dots. But what I want is to add a line between pos1 and pos2 for each individual. If I have 100 individual, there will be 100 short lines, connecting each pos1 and pos2. Is there any way I can do this in ggplot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `geom_segment`. Something like the following could work:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = original)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = pos1, col = "pos1")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = pos2, col = "pos2")) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = original,
                   y = pos1, yend = pos2)) +
  ylab("positions") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Position",
                      values = c(pos1 = "red",
                                 pos2 = "blue"))
```

[image]

Data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  original = 1:100,
  pos1 = rnorm(100),
  pos2 = rnorm(100, mean = 5)
)
```

If that doesn't work for you, do share a sample of your actual data.

Comment: Thanks, Lin. This is exactly what I was looking for! Greatly appreciate it!